# Enter singularity container running in slurm job

Tags: containers, slurm, singularity-container, sbatch

I'm running following `job_script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

singularity --debug run --app ${APP} \
                             --bind "vol/on/host":"vol/on/container" \
                             ${IMG_DIR}/${IMG_NAME}
```

with `sbatch` command (it is long running job):

```
sbatch -p ${QUEUE} --qos=${QOS} --job-name ${JOB_NAME} -o ${JOB_NAME}.o%J -e ${JOB_NAME}.e%J job_script.sh
```

What I want to achieve is to execute command in running container which is run in following slurm job:

```
$ squeue -u $USER
JOBID     ARRAY_TASKPARTITION NAME                                  USER      STATE     NODELIST(REASON) CPUS  NODES TRES_PERSTART_TIME            TIME
7988346   N/A       defq      rstudio                               myuser  RUNNING   nc023            1     1     N/A     2019-11-25T06:23:32   2:38:03
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `singularity exec` or `singularity run`, you're spawning a single process and you are unfortunately unable to run additional processes from within the same context as you might with `docker run ...`.

However, you can do this if you use `singularity instance start some_instance_name` instead. Afterwards, you can use `singularity shell` or `singularity exec` to access the same environment as the running job. [More details are available in the documentation](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.4/user-guide/running_services.html).

Comment: Great! It finally worked: `singularity instance.start <image> <instance_name> --> ssh <slurm job's node> --> singularity exec <instance_name> ls /`. Thank you @tsnowlan